Automorphy of the twisted representation
The Artin reciprocity says that if
$$
\chi: \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q) \to \mathbb C
$$
is a 1-dimensional representation of a finite Galois extension $K/ \mathbb Q$, then it corresponds to a Hecke character.
So if $\rho$ is a $\ell$-adic Galois representation that is attached to a regular algebraic cuspidal automorphic representation of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$ (more precisely, a strictly compatible system of $\ell$-adic Galois representations which is $\mathbb Q$-rational compatible), then the $L$-function
$$
L(s,\rho \otimes \chi)
$$
is automorphic.
In particular, if $\rho=\operatorname{Sym}^n(\rho_f)$ is a symmetric power of $\rho_f$ a $\ell$-adic Galois representation attached to a non-CM newform $f$, then by the recent work of Newton and Thorne, we have nice analytic properties (analytic continuation and functional equations) of
$$
L(s,\operatorname{Sym}^n(\rho_f) \otimes \chi).
$$
I wonder whether I understand correctly, or if there are some gaps I didn't catch, because at some points I just used the facts that I've read as sentences in some textbooks or papers. In that case, I would appreciate it if you point out those points.
Thank you so much.

I have a rough idea what your question is, but it's not 100% clear.  Can you be more precise what your exact question is?

@Kimball // I just want to confirm that the conclusion and the arguments are valid.
Currently, I am checking the details I skipped. For example, I just conveyed myself why Dirichlet characters can be seen as a unitary automorphic representation of $GL_1(\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$ yesterday.
There are many points like this. Nice analytic properties of $\rho_{\pi} \otimes \rho_{\pi'}$ is also one of them. So, I am skeptical whether what I know as superficial knowledge is correct. This is the reason for the question.

Yes, once you know that $\rho$ is automorphic, it follows that $L(s, \rho \otimes \chi)$ has good analytic properties for all Dirichlet characters $\chi$, and more generally so does $L(s, \rho \otimes \sigma)$ for any automorphic representation $\sigma$ of $GL_m$ (any $m$).
